# Hyperledger Fabric behind firewall/proxy

Tags: http, proxy, hyperledger, grpc, firewall

My Hyperledger Fabric enironment is behind a firewall, and I have to establish a connection with another organization. I know that Hyperledger uses GRPC for communication, and my organization has a HTTP proxy to access the internet, and I don't know if HTTP proxy solves this problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

IT teams of both the organizations need to open communication between each other. HTTP proxy is to cut your communication with actual internet. That is not going to work here, as both the orgs are individually controlled environments.

Once connectivity between orgs is established (like some n/w tunnel creation or something), you can work with the servers of the other org as if those are in your LAN. Your IT team should get involved here. All the best.